Use R3F drei view in nextjs
I'm playing around with Three for the first time, and trying to get React Three Fiber and React Three drei working in a NextJS environment.
I have a simple model working, but I can't figure out how to get the View component to work.
A simple scene:
// file: scene-simple.js
export default function Scene(props) {
  return (
    <Canvas
      onCreated={(state) => (state.gl.toneMapping = THREE.AgXToneMapping)}
      {...props}
    >
      <color attach={"background"} args={["hotpink"]} />
      <Model />
    </Canvas>
  );
}

// file: model.js
"use client";

export function Model() {
  return (
    <mesh>
      <boxGeometry />
      <meshStandardMaterial />
    </mesh>
  );
}

works fine if I import the Scene to a page with next/dynamic and ssr set to false:
const Scene = dynamic(() => import("./scene-simple"), {
  loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
  ssr: false,
});

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Scene />
    </main>
  );
}

But if I wrap a page in a layout that provides a scene (also with next/dynamic that renders <View.Port />), it doesn't work. It appears to me that I see a quick flash of the hotpink background from the Canvas, but then it switches to a blank canvas, as if there's some render problem with the View, but I'm not getting any errors.
// File: not-working/layout.js
export default function ViewLayout({ children }) {
  return <ThreeContainer>{children}</ThreeContainer>;
}

// File: not-working/three-container.js
const Scene = dynamic(() => import("./scene-with-view"), {
  loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
  ssr: false,
});

export function ThreeContainer({ children }) {
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <div
      className="relative w-full h-full minh-screen overflow-auto touch-auto"
      ref={ref}
    >
      {children}
      <Scene
        className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen -z-10"
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
        }}
        eventSource={ref}
        eventPrefix={"client"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// File: scene-with-view.js
export default function Scene(props) {
  return (
    <Canvas
      onCreated={(state) => (state.gl.toneMapping = THREE.AgXToneMapping)}
      {...props}
    >
      <color attach={"background"} args={["hotpink"]} />
      <View.Port />
    </Canvas>
  );
}

// File: page.js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <h1>This doesn't work</h1>
      </main>
      <ModelView />
    </>
  );
}

// File: not-working/model-view.js
"use client";

import { View } from "@react-three/drei";

export function ModelView() {
  return (
    <View>
      <mesh>
        <boxGeometry />
        <meshStandardMaterial />
      </mesh>
    </View>
  );
}

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get the Views to render in Next?
I thought maybe there's a problem with the way View renders, and I needed to make that a dynamic import as well, but if I make that change, I get max call-stack exceeded errors.
I've put both the simple, working model and the failing attempt with View up in a code sandbox here.
Interestingly, and probably related, I sometimes get a hydration error in the code sandbox (but I'm not seeing that at all in my local dev environment).
Any thoughts on how to make this work?

You should look at this example : react-three-next using tunnel-rat
Has done the job for me.

Hmm. That's actually where I started, but then I noticed that he had a pull request to move to the new drei-view, so I tried to use that ... but maybe it's not ready for primetime yet. Will look at react-three-next current again.
